# NextJs Server API File Access

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, serverless

I am struggling with reading files on the NextJS API.
My folder structure is as follows:

```
- data
  - file.txt
- pages
  - api
    - generateFile.ts
```

I want to be able to read `file.txt` inside the `generateFile.ts` but I am getting:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`

I read the files with the use of `fs.readFile` wrapped in `promisify`.

I cannot import that single file as the `data` folder contains multiple files and its not necessary to import them all every time the function gets called.

How can I make sure the `data` folder is included in the server build and can be read from?

I have been exploring and found that:

`.` directory contains

```
[
  '.env.example',
  '.next',
  '___next_launcher.cjs',
  '___vc',
  'node_modules',
  'package.json'
]
```

and "/" contains:

```
[
  'THIRD-PARTY-LICENSES.txt',
  'bin',
  'boot',
  'dev',
  'etc',
  'home',
  'lambda-entrypoint.sh',
  'lib',
  'lib64',
  'media',
  'mnt',
  'opt',
  'proc',
  'root',
  'run',
  'sbin',
  'srv',
  'sys',
  'tmp',
  'usr',
  'var'
]
```

**EDIT**
Well I have tried reading the contracts just by getting a path to that dir, added one line of code `path.join(process.cwd(),` data`);` and somehow `data` folder now got included in the build. Why?